# DRF - list of optionals field in serializer meta class

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have a model with about 45 fields that takes information about a company

```
class Company(models.Model):
    company_name = models.Charfield(max_length=255)
    .
    .
    .
    last_information = models.Charfield(max_lenght=255)
```

I also have a serializer that looks like so,

```
class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = "__all__"
        # some_optional_fields = ["field_1","field_2","field_3"]
```

however some of the fields are not required (about 20 of them to be precise). Is there a way where I can add those optional fields as a list or iterable of some sort to the metadata, example `some_optional_fields = ["field_1","field_2","field_3"]`, so that I won't have to explictly set those variables required argument to false like so

```
class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    company_name = serializers.Charfield(max_length=255, required=False)
    .
    .
    .
    last_information = serializers.Charfield(max_lenght=255, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = ["field_1","field_2","field_3",...,"field_45"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Options:

1. Use blank=True (and maybe null=True) on model field, and it should do it. DRF takes information from model.
2. use extra_kwargs: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#additional-keyword-arguments. But, I strongly suggest option#1 as if model is not blank=True you will end up with another error from model.

```py
class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = "__all__"
        some_optional_fields = ["field_1","field_2","field_3"]
        extra_kwargs = {}
        for field in some_optional_fields:
           extra_kwargs[field] = {'required': False, 'allow_blank': True}
```

Comment: One more remark: I strongly discourage using `fields = "__all__"`. It can lead to data leak, when you add some more fields with some confidential information and forgot to exclude those.

Answer (score 1):

You can use exclude() to exclude something from list

```
 class Meta:
    model = Company
    exclude = ('field_1', 'field_2')
```

Answer (score 1):

> Defaults to True. If you're using Model Serializer default value will be False if you have specified blank=True or default or null=True at your field in your Model.

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#required

So making your fields `null=True` and `blank=True` at the `models` will repeat the same behavior at `ModelSerializers`

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to add not required information from the `Meta` class using [`extra_kwargs`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context), like this:

```
class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = ["field_1","field_2","field_3",...,"field_45"]
        extra_kwargs = {
           'field_1': {'allow_null': True, 'required': False, 'blank': True}
           ...
        }
```

But you need to keep in mind that, if the field has already been explicitly declared on the serializer class, then the `extra_kwargs` option will be ignored.